# Insert into table with multiple rows in subquery

Tags: mysql, database, select, insert

I want to have results in a table where the data comes from 3 different tables.

For that I have tried to execute this query:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (id,date) 
VALUES 
   (
     (SELECT id FROM table1 
     UNION 
     SELECT id FROM table2 
     UNION 
     SELECT id FROM table3)
     ,
     (SELECT date FROM table1
     UNION 
     SELECT date FROM table2 
     UNION 
     SELECT date FROM table3)
  )
```

The result of this query is an error stating `cannot insert multiple rows`. Please help me to write this query correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) syntax is different to the [`INSERT ... VALUES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) syntax.  Also, you want to select both columns from each table at the same time:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (id, date)
SELECT id, date FROM table1 UNION
SELECT id, date FROM table2 UNION
SELECT id, date FROM table3
```